# QUICK SORT stack overflow c++ big numbers

Tags: c++, sorting, stack, quicksort

good day
I am trying to use quick sort with 10000 numbers but it is giving me stack overflow error. it works with random numbers but it does not with descending and ascending numbers.

'
thank you

```
void quickSort(long* array, long start, long last)
{
    if (start < last)
    {
        int p = partition(array, start, last);
        quickSort(array, start, p-1);
        quickSort(array, p + 1, last);
    }
}
int partition(long* array, long start, long last)//first partition
{
    int j = start + 1;
    for (long i = start + 1;i <= last;i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < array[start])
        {
            swap(array[i], array[j]);
            j++;
        }           

    }
    swap(array[start], array[j - 1]);
    return j - 1;
}
'
```

Comment: Please show a [Complete, minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So, with a 10000-element array, this is going to be a 10000-deep recursive call. Pulling a number out of a hat, let's say that each recursive call consumes 64 bytes (seems like a reasonable estimate for a simple stack frame, plus three `long` argument). It would see like this would take about 640kb of stack, which according to Bill Gates should be enough for everyone, so I'm kind of stumped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code is okay but your compiler uses stack very ineffectively. you just need to raise reserved stack amount. it happens much more often in debug profiles rather than release ones just because compiler preserves large stack chunks to check if stack was broken during execution of your procedure.

Comment: I fixed raising the stack amount. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

For sorted elements, you can avoid this problem by choosing the median of the three elements `array[start]`, `array[last]` and `array[(start + last + 1)/2]` as your pivot value.

```
int median_of_3(long* array, long start, long last)
{
    long a = (start + last + 1)/2, b = start, c = last;
    if (array[c] < array[a]) swap(array[c], array[a]);
    if (array[b] < array[a]) swap(array[b], array[a]);
    if (array[c] < array[b]) swap(array[c], array[b]);
    return partition(array, start, last);
}
```

An additional strategy to avoid a large stack depth is to calculate which partition is smaller, and recursively call the smaller one. The other partition can then be optimized into a loop (tail recursion optimization).

```
void quickSort(long* array, long start, long last)
{
    if (start >= last) return;

    int p = median_of_3(array, start, last);
    int next_start[2] = { start, p + 1 };
    int next_last[2] = { p - 1, last };
    bool i = p > (start + last)/2;
    quickSort(array, next_start[i], next_last[i]);
    /*
     * If the compiler does not optimize the tail call below into
     * a loop, it is easy to do the optimization manually.
     */
    quickSort(array, next_start[!i], next_last[!i]);
}
```

Introspection can also be used to avoid a large stack depth. You track your recursive call depth, and if it is "too deep", you fail safe into a different sorting strategy, like merge sort or heap sort. This is the behavior currently used by `std::sort`.

```
void introSortImpl(long* array, long start, long last, int depth)
{
    if (--depth == 0) {
        heapSort(array, start, last);
        return;
    }

    if (start >= last) return;

    int p = median_of_3(array, start, last);
    int next_start[2] = { start, p + 1 };
    int next_last[2] = { p - 1, last };
    bool i = p > (start + last)/2;
    introSortImpl(array, next_start[i], next_last[i], depth);
    introSortImpl(array, next_start[!i], next_last[!i], depth);
}

void introspectionSort(long* array, long start, long last)
{
    introSortImpl(array, start, last, log2(start - last) * 3);
}
```

Comment: Even median-of-three doesn't avoid the `O(n^2)` worst-case, it only reduces by a constant factor.

Comment: @o11c: *For sorted elements,...* -- by that I meant the input came in sorted to begin with, which is what the asker presented as the problem case. The *recursively call the smaller* partition does not solve quadratic worst case, it just avoids a stackoverflow. Only introspection deals with both stackoverflow and guaranteed O(n log n) behavior.

Comment: I don't know why articles call this tail recursion, it's just a loop that goes back and splits the larger partition into two partitions, repeating the process (recurse on smaller partition, loop on larger partition). Tail recursion normally refers to situations where a final recursive call that doesn't require any post call processing to be optimized by a compiler into a loop.

Comment: @rcgldr: If the compiler can do the optimization, the 2nd of the two recursive calls is tail recursive that can be made into a loop. If the compiler cannot, then the optimization has be to be implemented manually by the programmer.

Comment: @jxh - I posted an answer showing a common example of using recursion only on the smaller partition. It's not an example of tail recursion. The original question includes an example of tail recursion on the second call, but this doesn't prevent stack overflow, since the first / recursive call worst case stack usage is O(n).

Comment: @jxh - with the original question example code, data already sorted or reverse sorted will use O(n) stack space. The example I posted has worst case O(log2(n)) stack space, it's worst case time complexity is still O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Example of Lomuto partition scheme like quicksort that uses recursion on the smaller partition, updates l or r, then loops back to split the larger partition into two partitions, repeating the process. Worst case stack space is O(log2(n)) which should avoid stack overflow. Worst case time complexity is still O(n^2) (depending on how partition is implemented).

Some call this example a half recursion. It's not an example of tail recursion, since tail recursion means that the recursive function just returns after calling itself. The second call in the original question example is a tail call.

```
void quicksort(int * tab, int l, int r)
{
   int q;
   while(l < r)
   {
      q = partition(tab, l, r);
      if(q - l < r - q) {     // recurse into the smaller partition
         quicksort(tab, l, q - 1);
         l = q + 1;
      } else {
         quicksort(tab, q + 1, r);
         r = q - 1;
      }
   }                          // loop on the larger partition
}
```